# Entity Framework 5 and Pivot table, How?

Tags: entity-framework

I've got a simple table:
Year - Quarter - Value
2012     1        177
2012     2        213
2012     3        168
2012     4        313

I want to return the data via Linq as this:

Year - Q1 - Q2 - Q3 - Q4
2012   177  213  168  313

Any suggestions on the best way to do this? I assume some sort of Pivot?

TIA
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I worked out:

```
 Metrics.GroupBy(c => c.Year) 
 .Select(g => new {
Year = g.Key,
Q1 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 1).Sum(c => c.Value), 
      Q2 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 2).Sum(c => c.Value), 
Q3 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 3).Sum(c => c.Value),
Q4 = g.Where(c => c.Quarter == 4).Sum(c => c.Value) 
})
```

Any better suggestions?