# Merge Two or More Entity Framework Entities with Dynamic Columns?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, sqlite

I've got a project that uses an SQLite database with Entity Framework and VB.Net. The database is complex but everything is set up well for accessing the data in individual tables.

What I need is a way to transform (pivot?) the data from two or more tables and get a resulting table with columns that are generated dynamically based on the data in the original tables. As an example, if I start with two tables that look like this:

```
Table 1
Id      Data    Field
1       17      1
1       34      2
1       72      3
2       23      1
2       11      2
2       46      3
3       1       1
3       19      2
3       24      3

Table 2
Id      Data    Field
1       abc     4
1       def     5
1       ghi     6
2       jkl     4
2       mno     5
2       pqr     6
3       stu     4
3       vwx     5
3       yz      6
```

I need to end up with the following as the resulting table:

```
Id  Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6
1   17      34      72      abc     def     ghi
2   23      11      46      jkl     mno     pqr
3   1       19      24      stu     vwx     yz
```

Simplified, obviously, but I hope the general layout is clear. At design time I do **not** know how many fields (and thus columns in the resulting merged table) there will be. I do know, however, that all the Data in Table 1 will be numeric and all the Data in Table 2 will be text.

Obviously I can loop through the data and construct a DataTable dynamically in code, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a more efficient way to do it, that can be used with data binding to a datagrid. I've tried various LINQ Joins (using System.Linq.Dynamic) but I always run into problems with the fact that I don't know how many of the fields there will be.

Another important factor is that this data will need to be editable, so when the user updates a value I'll need to have some way to figure out which row in which original table is being edited.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: So many duplicates! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160817/pivot-in-c-sharp-entity-framework-3-5), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267982/entity-framework-5-and-pivot-table-how), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082057/how-to-use-pivot-table-with-entityframework) and counting. Many without answers because the simple conclusion is: it can't be done in any quick standard way.

Comment: They don't seem to be asking quite the same thing - those questions seem to be related to a more simple pivot, but I'm looking to merge _and_ modify the structure of the tables in a dynamic way at runtime, not just display them in a different way.

Comment: OK. Since you add the entity-framework tag it seems you want to do the pivot by an EF query. If you intend to do it in any other way maybe you'd like to explain how EF is related? Anticipating on this I can say that you won't be able to use EF to address the dynamic table. Building the table should probably be done in a stored procedure. Saving data is a matter of tracking row key + column name back to the original record, probably in a stored procedure again.